# How could I make use of the sticky footer in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Lately I have been trying to get into Bootstrap 4. I know that Bootstrap by default offers a layout for navigation, body and footer etc. and this has been developed over the time to perform or appear better. I found some of the examples on Bootstrap and that I would be able to use a [sticky footer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) (rather than a fixed footer) for my web page. For some reason I am not able to make it work.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/9v4qkodf/) is what I have tried:

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

main>.container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

.footer>.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

code {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5">Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
    <p class="lead">Pin a footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>main &gt; .container</code>.</p>
    <p>Back to <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer/">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
  </div>
</main>

<footer class="footer mt-auto py-3">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

What code of given example page am I missing? The footer's behaviour found within my example is not the same as the one found within the example page, because when I add multiple elements (e.g. add around ten paragraph elements) it could be noticed how the footer does not "stick" like the one found within the [example page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/).

Comment: use `position: sticky` in `.footer`

Comment: That seems to work, although I'm quite curious why I cannot find this property within the example. Would the behaviour with the use of given CSS property be exactly identical (so that no other visual bugs might occur)? @JoykalInfotech

Comment: It appears more like a fixed element rather than the way Bootstrap's behaviour intended for this element to work. Also is not supported on IE.

Comment: @Barrosy You can try `position: fixed;`, because `position: sticky;` is [not supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=position%20sticky)

Comment: It's not the same behaviour as Bootstrap 4's Sticky footer by doing this. My question was how to get the identical thing (sticky footer page example) going on. @fen1x